# footnote in \Xarrangement{paragraph} does not go to the next line in reledmac

Tags: paragraphs, reledmac, persian, critical

Dear members of this communication,
I use reledmac for a critical edition of a Persian book. During my work, I faced a problem and would be grateful if you could answer it. Using \Xarrangement{paragraph}, when I write something lengthy in footnotes, the text does not go to the next line and starts to use the margin. It also sometimes corrupts all the other footnotes in that page. In addition, if the blank space after your previous footnote is not enough to write a new one, it goes to the next line and some blank space would be left in the previous line.  I would be thankful if you could help me. Here is a sample of my work:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4]{book}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\usepackage{polyglossia,fontspec,xunicode}
\usepackage{libertine}
 \usepackage{ragged2e}
\setmainlanguage{Persian}
\setotherlanguage{english}

\usepackage[noend, nopenalties, nofamiliar, noeledsec,series={A,B,C,D}]{reledmac}

% \usepackage[advancedshiftedpstarts,nomaxlines]{reledpar}
\usepackage[top=3cm,left=5cm,right=4cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{bidipoem}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\usepackage{bidi}

\makeatletter

\let\Afootnoterule=\right@footnoterule
\let\Bfootnoterule=\right@footnoterule 
\renewcommand{\Cfootnoterule}{\right@footnoterule}


\interfootnotelinepenalty=10000

\makeatother
\unsetLTR

\AtEveryPend{\vspace{30mm}}

\sidenotemargin{inner}
\linenummargin {outer}
\setsidenotesep{ $1$ }
\settextfont{IRNazanin}


\Xarrangement[A]{paragraph}
\Xarrangement[B]{paragraph}
\Xarrangement[C]{normal}
\Xinplaceofnumber[B]{10pt}
\Xinplaceoflemmaseparator{10pt}

\Xparafootsep{$||$}
\Xafternote[B]{2pt}
\Xafternumber[B]{4pt}
 \Xlemmaseparator[B]{]}
\Xafterrule[B]{5pt}
\Xafterrule[A]{5pt}
\Xafterrule[C]{5pt}
\setmsdataseries{A}
\firstlinenum{1} 
\linenumincrement{1} 
\setsidenotesep{ $|$ }



\begin{document}
  \renewcommand\poemcolsepskip{1.5 cm} 
\beginnumbering

\pstart 
\msdata{BCDE}
\skipnumbering \begin{center}
    \Large
    به نام ایزد
\edtext{
 بخشاینده و بخشایشگر
} {\Bfootnote{بخشایندۀ بخشایشگر مهربان دادگر 
     [خط بعد:] کتاب ارداویراف ازگفتۀ شعر زرتشت بهرام (CD)
      / بخشایندۀ بخشایشگر مهربان دستگیر [خط بعد:] آغاز کتاب اردای‌ویراف‌نامه (E)}}
    \end{center}
\normalsize

\skipnumbering  \hfill \break


\begin{traditionalpoem}

شهنشاه اردشیر
\ledsidenote{[0 پ]}
 از فر دادار    
&   گرفت آن پادشاهی را سزاوار   \\  \\
همه نیکی ز عدل
\edtext{پادشا}{\Bfootnote{پادشاه (BD)}}
     دان    
& 
        همیشه شاه عادل باد شادان
        \\  \\
ز عدل او به ایران و خراسان  &   شده بر مردمان عیش و خور آسان    \\  \\
ز دادش یافت آرام این جهان باز   &
    برآسودند از آن کین مردمان
    \edtext{باز}{\Bfootnote{راز (CD)}}
            \\  \\
چو بشنیدند از آن گفتار آواز &   برآوردند باز از کنج پرواز   \\  \\
چو روز
 بخت‌شان از
 \edtext{  که}{\Bfootnote{کوه (CD)}}
  برآمد
    &   دگر ره شوق دین‌شان در سر آمد    \\  \\
همه رفتند پیش
\edtext{ 
تخت     
} {\lemma{مصرع اول}
 \Bfootnote{تا قبل از «تخت» برگ نسخه تاخورده. در حاشیه به خطی دیگر: همه رفتند پیش تخت شاهی (B)}

}
شاهی &
\edtext{زبان‌ها پردعا و}{\Bfootnote{ ندید از شه به دل جز  (B)}}
     نیک‌خواهی  
\\  \\

منش کن پاک با دادار یزدان   &   
\edtext{نیت}{\Bfootnote{پتت (E)}}
 با اعتقادت راست گردان   \\ \\
دل پاک و تن پاکیزه و صاف    &   بنوش این باده ای اردای‌ویراف     \\ \\
بخورد اردایویراف آن قدر می  &   دگر باره چنین گفتند با وی    \\ \\
بپرسیدند کاردا چون رسیدی    &   بگو ما را همه چیزی که دیدی   \\ \\
که تا ما نیز این احوال دانیم    &   که 
\edtext{دیری}{\Bfootnote{دیدی (E)}}
 شد که تا در بند آنیم    \\ \\
نخستین گفت چیزی آوریدم  &   چو باشم 
\edtext{خورده}{\Bfootnote{خورد (E)}}
 پرسش می‌کنیدم   \\ \\
بیاوردند چیزی چون بخورد او  &   سپاس
\edtext{و}{\Bfootnote{<و> (E)}}
شکر یزدان را بکرد او     \\ \\
بگفت 
\edtext{اکنون}{\Bfootnote{آنگه (CD)}}
\edtext{دبیری}{\Bfootnote{دبیرم (E)}}
  پیشم آرید &   مر این گفتار را بازی مدارید  \\ \\
\edtext{چو}{\Bfootnote{که (CD)}} 
بنویسید نسخه زان فرستید &   پدیرید
\edtext{و}{\Bfootnote{<و> (D)}}
 همه کیهان فرستید    \\ \\
که تا معلوم گردد مردمان را  &   بدانند آن بهشت و دوزخان را   \\ \\
که یزدان راستان و بی‌گناهان     &   همیشه دوست دارد در دو کیهان \\  \\
بدیشان در ز 
\edtext{خوره}{\Bfootnote{خره (C)}} 
واگشاید     &   همه راز 
\edtext{نهان } {\Bfootnote{حرف اول بی‌نقطه (B)}}
پیدا نماید  \\  \\
چنین مردی بجز اردای ویراف   &   ندانیم ای شه با داد و انصاف \\  \\
برو داریم یکسر اعتمادا  &    که جان آن اشایه  شاد بادا  \\  \\
\edtext{یزشن}{\Bfootnote{یزش (CDE)}}
سازیم گردش ما دگر شش    &   همی باشیم گردش نیز هر شش    \\  \\
هر آن نیرنگ کاو را هست در دین   &   بجا آریم ما ای شاه بهدین    \\  \\



همیشه قیمت نیکی بدانند  &
\edtext{روان را}{\Bfootnote{روان‌ها (CD)}} 
از بدی‌ها وارهانند   \\ \\
دبیر آمد سوی اردای ویراف    &   بدو گفتا که بشنو از من اوصاف     \\ \\
حدیثش یک به یک بنویس 
\edtext{با شرح}{\Bfootnote{تا سرح (E)}}
    &   از این قصه سخن‌ها را مکن طرح     \\ \\
دبیرش کلک و کاغذ سوی او برد &   دل و جان را بدان گفتار بسپرد     \\ \\
چو از مشک سیه نزدیک کافور   &   پیام آورد از فرمان دستور     \\ \\
برآمد 
\ledsidenote{[6 پ]}
\edtext{هندوی}{\Bfootnote{هندی (CD)}}
 بر سان خاور    &   نگاریدش برو بر نام داور
\end{traditionalpoem}  \skipnumbering 
\skipnumbering 
\begin{center}
    \large
\hidenumbering 
\edtext{
پاسخ‌دادن ویراف از نزول سروش بر او و 
\edtext{بردن}{\Bfootnote{بردل (B)}}
 او را به عالم 
}{\lemma{[عنوان:]}\Bfootnote{
    گفتار اندر شرح‌دادن ارداویراف از احوال بهشتیان (C)، D عنوان ندارد،
    بازآمدن اردای از آن جهان و گفتن حقیقت‌های بهشت‌وران(؟) بهشتیان (E)
    }}
\hidenumbering
\end{center} 
% A \noindent will be inserted before foo
% \linebreak
% \newline
% \skipnumbering  
 \hfill
 \break
\normalsize
\advanceline{-1}
% \setline{156}
\begin{traditionalpoem}
چنین گفت 
آنگهی اردای ویراف   &   که چون خوردم سه جام بادۀ صاف     \\ \\
شدم در 
\edtext{خواب}{\Bfootnote{+و (CD)}}
 از من هوش شد دور   &   سروش آمد به سان عالمی نور    \\ \\
سلامم کرد و می‌پرسید بسیار  &   تو گفتی مهربانم بود و غمخوار     \\ \\
درست و 
\edtext{شاد و}{\Bfootnote{<و> (CDE)}}
 به گفت آمدی گش &   از آن پتیاره‌مند و جای ناخوش     \\ \\
سرای 
\edtext{اندهان}{\Bfootnote{اندوهان (CD)}}
 و خانۀ غم  &   رباط 
 \edtext{محنت و}{\Bfootnote{محنتی (D)}}
 وادی ماتم   \\ \\
\edtext{جهانی}{\Bfootnote{جهان (E)}}
\edtext{سیچ‌مند و}{\Bfootnote{سیچ‌مندی (CE)}}
پر انائی    &   که او را پیشه باشد بی‌وفائی  \\ \\
بیاسود از نسیم بوی او مغز   &   میان باد دیدم 
 \edtext{صورتی}{\Bfootnote{صورت (B) / صورنی (D)}} 
 نغز     \\ \\
که هرگز مثل آن صورت ندیدم   &   ز دیدارش به دندان لب گزیدم   \\ \\
نیارم کرد وصف خوبی او   &   فرو ماندم در آن معجوبی او    \\ \\
نظر هر چند می‌کردم درو بیش  &   به چشمم بود نور آن اشو بیش   \\ \\
به هر اندام او کافتاد دیدار &   نظر برداشتن زو بود دشوار
\end{traditionalpoem}  
 \stopmsdata
\pend 
\endnumbering
  \end{document}
```

Comment: hi, mir. please provide a Minimal Worjking Example reproducting your bug.

Comment: I edited my question and added a sample. Thank you for your consideration.

Comment: @Maïeul Did you find a way to solve this problem?

Comment: sorry, I have not a lot of time yet. Will try this afternnon

Comment: Thank you very much! So kind of you Maïeul!

Comment: I am afraid there is som imcompatibility with the xepersian package. If i delete it, it's work. The problem is that xepersian redefine, indirectly, the output routine. I think you don't need xepersian. You can make all your RTL settings using the bidi command inside the "hooks" command of reledmac

Comment: Thank you for your response. Unfortunately, I could not solve the problem by using bidi command. Could you possibly give me your edited code? In addition, I understood that by using Xarrangement{normal} the problem would be solved; however, the command \let\Bfootnoterule=\right@footnoterule would not worked and the ruler will be printed in the left side! This is another problem.

Comment: I have not try with bidi command, especillay because for me all persian glyphs are identical, and it is very difficult for me to see the difference. But, on stackexchange, you will find many topic about reledmac and bidi.The main idea is to call the switching command inside the reledmac command, using the reledmac "Hook".

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will try to find a way to solve the problem.

Comment: your welcome. If you have question, you can open new topic, or just let chat here.